# Can Castle Windsor scan zip files for assemblies?

Tags: .net, plugins, castle-windsor

I am curious if there is a strategy I can plug into Castle Windsor that would let it scan assemblies in an arbitrary way, i.e. not just those in memory or those in a directory. It seems easy enough to build the discovery mechanism ourselves, load those assemblies, then use Castle to scan them. But I wondered if there was a mechanism built in?

One idea is that a NuGet package might be executed directly in place without unpacking through strategic use of discovery and .net assembly resolution events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing like that is built in.